# COPY Worksheet from one Workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro that opens a second workbook loading a csv file. I would like to copy the sheet containing the csv file (which is "Sheet1") of the new opened workbook into the starting workbook. I keep getting a subscript out of range error when executing the line to copy the sheet.

```
Public Sub LoadCSV()
Dim FileName As String
Dim Path As String
Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook ' macro workbook
Dim CSVWorkBook As Workbook     ' csv workbook

Set CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

'File Dialog box to import CSV file
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV File (*.CSV,*.csv")
'Workbooks.Open FileName
Set CSVWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

CSVWorkBook.Activate
CSVWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy _
After:=CurrentWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)


    'Extracts the Path from the CSV file Path to be used later in function
Path = Left(FileName, InStrRev(FileName, "\"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I can think of:

`Sheets.Count` refers to the currently `Active` workbook. This is explicitly made as `CSVWorkBook`:

```
CSVWorkBook.Activate
CSVWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy _
After:=CurrentWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
```

So, change the above 3 lines to the following:

```
With CurrentWorkbook
    CSVWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy _
        After:=.Worksheets(.Sheets.Count)
End With
```

If that still raises a subscript out of range error on the `Copy` statement, then it is because there is no such sheet named "Sheet1" in that workbook. Typically, a CSV file only has a single "worksheet" and that worksheet is named like the filename (without an extension).

Rather than trying to determine the sheet's name, since we know there should only be 1 sheet in a CSV file, do:

```
With CurrentWorkbook
    CSVWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy _
        After:=.Worksheets(.Sheets.Count)
End With
```

Comment: I will try in the AM.

Comment: The last code segment worked, so refer with the qualified named object and copy back to the current object. Cool, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the copying line you are using "Sheets.Count" which at that moment refers to sheets in "CSVWorkbook" which you just activated before yet you are inserting in CurrentWorkbook. It seems to be the case that CSVWorkbook actually has more sheets than CurrentWorkbook. If that is the case, then you are indeed trying to insert sheets past the last sheet of this workbook and that will trigger a "Subscript out of range" type of error.

Comment: I changed the line in question to the following : CSVWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy _
after:=CurrentWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3"), I still receive the subscript out of range error.

Comment: In the execution window (Ctrl + G in the VBA editor) try checking both worksheets individually to check where the problem is. Test for CSVWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") and CurrentWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3"). Possibly one of them has a typo in it or does not exist.

Comment: I added a line after making the CSVWorkBook active to make the sheet         CSVWorkBook.Activate
CSVWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate <- I now receive an "Subscript out of range" on this line.

Comment: Yes that happens because your workbook is not activated before activating the worksheet.